# Select where all of list in 1 table matches some in another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I can't believe I'm the first person to ever ask this, but I'm having trouble finding the correct way to achieve the following query. 
Logically it seems quite simple, but I'm struggling to code it

I have 2 tables, I would like to get all the cars and cust_id's from table 1, where the complete list of colours from table 2 (grouped by car) matches the colours from table 1. 
The sticking point is that not all of the colours in table 1 have to be in table 2

I've been experimenting with joins, exists and intersects but to no avail 
All the code similar to below will match if at least 1 items match, but not all.

```
SELECT 
a.Cust_Id,
a.Car
FROM Table1 a
JOIN Table2 b ON a.Car = b.Car and a.Colour = b.Colour
GROUP BY a.Cust_Id, a.Car
```

It's part of a much larger script doing many other things so I have used the cars/colours as an example, so appreciate it doesn't make much sense in this context.

Table1

[image]

Table2

[image]

Expected Output

```
Output
1   Audi
1   Ford
2   VW
```

Comment: Added table examples and expected output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, in the answer yes, but not in OP's query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each group, count the number of `NULL` colors from `Table1` and make sure that this count is zero.  This would mean that every color in the second table mapped to a color in the first table.

```
SELECT b.Cust_Id,
       b.Car
FROM Table1 a
RIGHT JOIN
(
    SELECT 1 AS Cust_ID, Car, Colour
    FROM Table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, Car, Colour
    FROM Table2
) b
    ON a.Car = b.Car       AND
       a.Colour = b.Colour AND
       a.Cust_ID = b.Cust_ID
GROUP BY b.Cust_Id,
         b.Car
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN a.Colour IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Note closely that I used a subquery to enhance the second table of color requirements.  I added a `Cust_ID` column, under the assumption that every customer has the same requirements, to make the join easier to handle and analyze.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I agree with your logic, although this output gives me Ford and VW for Cust 1 and Audi and VW for Cust 2 as it's matching on the fact 1 of the items exists in table 2, not all.

Comment: Do you want each car to have _all_ the colors in the second table?

Comment: Yes, all the records from table1 are to displayed only if all the colours are in table2. So Audi and Ford will show for cust_id 1 because both colours are in table2. But for VW Table1 must have Blue and Black

Comment: You need to use full outer join.

Comment: With your query or my original one? Both result in the same results as before.

Comment: @gregdanish I updated my query, please try it again.

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly for the example. In reality, there is an ever growing number of cust_id's in Table1, so I'm not sure how I would scale up the "union all" to not only include them all as well as not having to hard code the script every time a new item is added.

Comment: This would be far less work than you think.  You could use some dynamic SQL to generate the customer IDs, but I do think that information should ideally be present.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to this as I see you already have a solution, but here's some SQL I came up in case it might be of some use. The way I read the question, table1 might be a wish list of cars from various customers, and table2 a car dealer's list of what they can supply. The dealer wants to know which customers are interested in their full range of colours for each car:

```
select w.cust_id, w.car
from table1 w join table2 s
  on w.car=s.car and w.colour=s.colour
group by w.cust_id, w.car
having count(s.car)=(select count(*) from table2 where car=w.car);
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I've solved it, slightly amended the RIGHT JOIN criteria and seems to work with the tests I've run.

```
SELECT b.Cust_Id,
       b.Car
FROM Table1 a
RIGHT JOIN
(
    SELECT b.Cust_ID, a.Car, a.Colour
    FROM Table2 a, Table1 b
    ) b
    ON a.Car = b.Car       AND
       a.Colour = b.Colour AND
       a.Cust_ID = b.Cust_ID
GROUP BY b.Cust_Id,
         b.Car
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN a.Colour IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```